# R Terra- extracting LULC to a shapefile of municipalities, counts of each classification

Tags: extract, gis, raster, terra

I have a categorical land use raster (habitat_raster.tif) and a shapefile of ~200 municipalities (municipality_shapefile.shp). I would like to get an area of each habitat type within each municipality. Muncipality is uniquely identified by a code.

The raster has 2 classes associated with the ID's based on water level (class_low, class_high). See example of attribute table below:

| ID | class_low | class_high |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Open Water | Open Water |
| 2 | Forest | Flooded Forest |
| 3 | Herbaceous | Flooded Herbaceous |

See below code so far:

```
#load in municipality as sf object
tmp_municipality_sf <- 
  st_read('spatial_analyses/data/municipality_shapefile.shp') %>% 
  # same projection string as habitat raster
  st_transform(crs = '+proj=aea +lat_0=-6 +lon_0=-63 +lat_1=-13 +lat_2=3 +x_0=6377563.4 +y_0=6356256.9 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs')

# load raster data 
habitat_raster <- 
  # CRS: Albers Equal Area, resolution (100 x 100):
  terra::rast('data_cleaning/spatial/habitat_raster.tif')

# load raster attribute table
habitat_classes <-
read_csv(habitat_classes.csv)

# set habitat classes as levels
levels(habitat_raster) <- habitat_classes

# crop raster to municipality shapefile
habitat_crop <- 
  habitat_raster %>% 
  terra::crop(tmp_municipality_sf)
```

I've tried using terra::extract(), but it provided me with a dataframe of ID, class_low and it isn't associated with the municipality code.

```
municipality_extract <- 
  tmp_municipality_sf %>% 
  group_by(code) %>% 
  terra::vect() %>% 
  terra::extract(habitat_crop,
                 .,
                 mask = TRUE)
```

I've also tried to put these values into the municipality's spatial dataframe with:

```
municipaltiy_extract_df <-
  tmp_municipality_sf %>%
  mutate(habitats = tmp_municipality_sf %>% 
           terra::vect() %>% 
           terra::extract(habitat_crop,
                          .) %>% 
           # pulls a vector of values for each municipality
           pull())
```

I'm not sure if I can do terra::zonal() instead, and use each municipality shape as the 'zone'.
But what I want is a dataframe with municipality code and the area of each habitat class (km^2) in columns. I thought the best way to do this would be to get a count of pixels from each habitat class and then calculate area?

| mun_code | ID_1 | ID_2 | ID_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 10000 | 5000 | 2000 |
| 101 | 9500 | 4000 | 1500 |

Comment: Can you please rewrite your question and include a self-contained reproducible example? See the examples that come with R  for the functions that you mention.

Answer (score 2):

This has been simplified in recent versions of terra.

Example data

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.7.29
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
r <- round((r-50)/100)
levels(r) <- data.frame(id=1:5, name=c("forest", "water", "urban", "crops", "grass"))
```

To count the number of cells for each category, by zone

```
e <- extract(r, v, fun="table", na.rm=TRUE)

# add the names
data.frame(NAME_2=v$NAME_2[e[,1]], e[,-1])
#             NAME_2 forest water urban crops grass
#1          Clervaux      0     0    28   459    74
#2          Diekirch      2   123   200    66     3
#3           Redange      0   109   170   170    17
#4           Vianden      0    31    39    57     3
#5             Wiltz      0     1   161   303     8
#6        Echternach     14    76   233     1     0
#7            Remich     50   147    24     0     0
#8      Grevenmacher     19   221   137     2     0
#9          Capellen      0    25   305     0     0
#10 Esch-sur-Alzette      0   190   229    15     0
#11       Luxembourg      0   184   223    16     0
#12           Mersch      0   167   239    14     0
```

And you can use extract(  , `exact=TRUE`) to not only consider entire cells, but also sum the fractions of cells that are covered.

You are using an equal area coordinate reference system (crs). That means that you may be able to safely multiply these values with `prod(res(r))` to get the areas.

That would make no sense with my example, as the crs is lon/lat. To account of that, you can use `expanse` or `zonal`. With `expanse` it goes like this:

```
zone <- rasterize(v, r, "NAME_2")
expanse(r, unit="km", byValue=TRUE, zones=zone, wide=TRUE)[,-1]
#               zone    forest       water     urban      crops     grass
#1          Diekirch  1.110530  68.3111509 111.08929  36.621714  1.662192
#2        Echternach  7.784033  42.2720014 129.61202   0.555644  0.000000
#3      Grevenmacher 10.591752 123.1872271  76.33934   1.114409  0.000000
#4            Remich 27.951955  82.1601534  13.41321   0.000000  0.000000
#5          Capellen  0.000000  13.9496106 170.14699   0.000000  0.000000
#8  Esch-sur-Alzette  0.000000 106.2479147 128.04839   8.392079  0.000000
#10       Luxembourg  0.000000 102.7248564 124.44157   8.921887  0.000000
#11           Mersch  0.000000  92.9318291 133.02760   7.792452  0.000000
#12          Redange  0.000000  60.6687117  94.55675  94.459184  9.444716
#14          Vianden  0.000000  17.1997610  21.63354  31.602716  1.662192
#15            Wiltz  0.000000   0.5546965  89.26629 168.018372  4.437191
#17         Clervaux  0.000000   0.0000000  15.49914 253.829542 40.900555
```

For `zonal` you need to first compute the area of each cell.

```
x <- cellSize(r, unit="km")
zonal(x, c(zone, r), fun="sum", wide=TRUE)
#             NAME_2    forest       water     urban      crops     grass
#1          Diekirch  1.110530  68.3111509 111.08929  36.621714  1.662192
#2        Echternach  7.784033  42.2720014 129.61202   0.555644  0.000000
#3      Grevenmacher 10.591752 123.1872271  76.33934   1.114409  0.000000
#4            Remich 27.951955  82.1601534  13.41321   0.000000  0.000000
#5          Capellen  0.000000  13.9496106 170.14699   0.000000  0.000000
#8  Esch-sur-Alzette  0.000000 106.2479147 128.04839   8.392079  0.000000
#10       Luxembourg  0.000000 102.7248564 124.44157   8.921887  0.000000
#11           Mersch  0.000000  92.9318291 133.02760   7.792452  0.000000
#12          Redange  0.000000  60.6687117  94.55675  94.459184  9.444716
#14          Vianden  0.000000  17.1997610  21.63354  31.602716  1.662192
#15            Wiltz  0.000000   0.5546965  89.26629 168.018372  4.437191
#17         Clervaux  0.000000   0.0000000  15.49914 253.829542 40.900555
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, can you clarify as to whether this provides a pixel count for each class or an area?

Comment: I now show both the cell count and the area

Comment: Hi there, this worked for a while but with a new set of polygons these methods no longer worked, with a few errors taking place. First, it's telling me that the arguments 'zones' and 'wide' are unused when attempting expanse(). Second, some of my municipalities disappear at this step. Could the second issue be because some of the polygon areas are overlapping?

Comment: if the above does not work for you then you need to first update the "terra" package. If the above works, but it does not work with other data, then you should probably ask another question --- I cannot guess what it might be.

Comment: @RobertHijmans With `zonal`, one step i.e. `cellSize` is extra. So, it will take more time than `expanse`. Am I correct?